# Jquery lightbox with carasol

Tags: jquery

Hi wonder if someone can point me in the right direction.

I am looking at creating a lightbox with carasol inside

to explain a little more.

There are 4 images on the home page, which when clicked launch a lightbox which then displays X div.

the usr can then click left or right on the pop up and it will in turn slide through all the div.

suppose what i am asking is does anyone know if a plug in to do such a thing, i know there are many for lightbox and many for carasol but im after one that does both

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, try this: http://fancybox.net/home and check out Image Gallery example.

Comment: thank you for your reply. this iamage might explaine what i need http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7175/6766464403_eac2047f87_b.jpg. red beling close, green being next and prev, and the user in the diagramme would have clicked image 3 on the first screen

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [scrollview](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/scrollview/). Here's an example that probably looks like what you're looking for: [horizontal scroll with pagination](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/scrollview/scrollview-paging-example.html).